# Customising access logs in spring-boot - undertow

Tags: spring-boot, undertow, access-log

I have undertow properties configured in spring-boot - application.yaml as below:

```
undertow:
    accesslog:
      dir: logs/access
      enabled: true
      pattern: '%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b %D'
```

I want set custom value to one of the attribute in pattern, say for **%u** I want to log modified value for user, how can I achieve that? I have current code in-progress as below:

```
@Component
public class UndertowAccessLogHandler implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableUndertowWebServerFactory> {

    private final ServerProperties serverProperties;

    public UndertowAccessLogHandler(ServerProperties serverProperties) {
        this.serverProperties = serverProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableUndertowWebServerFactory factory) {
        String pattern = serverProperties.getUndertow().getAccesslog().getPattern();
        factory.setAccessLogPattern(pattern.replace("%u", "sample_user"));
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the expected result in more systematic way?

Comment: Before anyone duplicates effort, this was also [asked on Spring boot's issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34745). Please consider the time of people who might be willing to help you before cross-posting in multiple places, particularly without making it clear that you have done so.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have another question - in above code I am setting modified log pattern with test value "sample_user". How can I set it to some other value coming in request header ?